# SASS and Compass with WP and Font-face

Tags: sass, font-face, compass-sass

I am having trouble getting fonts to work on my sass website. I am new to sass and compass and everything is working except the fonts.

I generated the font-face files and put them in a folder library/font

In the config.rb file I added the following lines:

```
css_dir = "/"
sass_dir = "library/sass"
images_dir = "library/img"
fonts_dir = "library/font"
javascripts_dir = "library/js"
```

The generated font-face path in the style.css has a forward slash at the start.

```
src: url('///fonts/fontawesome-webfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('///fonts/fontawesome-webfont-webfont.svg') format('svg'), url('///fonts/fontawesome-webfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('///fonts/fontawesome-webfont-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the Sass look like that calls your font file?

Comment: It's not only the slash. The resulting path is completely different from what you've got in the config.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the font names called in the scr: were incorrect doh. However that did not solve my problem.

The fonts were being generated and had a `/` before the path name to the fonts folder. So I had to add this line in the config.rb file to fix it:

```
relative_assets = true
```

I am not sure if this was the correct way to get it all working. So any suggestions for next time would be great.

Thank you people for your time.